# What is the point of a .NET 4.0 TryCatch Activity if the Finally is not guaranteed to execute?

Tags: .net-4.0, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

I was designing an Activity today and I came across an issue by which rethrowing an exception within the Catch of a TryCatch block does not execute the Finally which is also associated with it.  Upon further investigation I came across the following

http://connect.microsoft.com/wf/feedback/details/557601/try-catch-activity-never-executes-finally-if-exception-propagates

Can anyone explain to me what the use of the finally block is in this activity if it is not guaranteed to execute?

The only case I can see is if you have nested try blocks.

Comment: reminded me of this... http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/My-Tales.aspx

Answer (score 5):

if you follow some links from that connect page you will reach [this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wfprerelease/thread/d54bd44a-24b7-4b0b-aa3c-f4553e00c820) where you may find an answer... the gist is:

The normal WF functions like

```
try
{
    Environment.FailFast("Game Over.");
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not Called");
}
```

the solution is (quoting steve danielson from that page):
*If you specify Cancel as the behavior for unhandled exceptions escaping the root of the workflow then it should give the desired behavior. I have passed this feedback along and will ensure that the documentation is updated to reflect this.*

ie `Workflowapplication.OnUnhandledException  = UnhandledExceptionAction.Cancel`

HTH